# Skype For Business Bot Not Responding

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-for-business

We use MBF for over a year now, and in the past month initialized a Skype for business bot. After creating it and configuring it in our domain - we let one of our customers use it - giving them the bot user name. 
From some reason they don't get any response from the bot, while we do get a response. We checked our nodejs server in debug mode as well while they tried to send a message to the bot - but couldn't find a clue. Nothing happens. 
This is our application Id - be0ad30a-12e2-49e1-bfb2-35807e196adf.
Can you please help us? Is there anything we should have checked/configured for the bot so that users from different domains will be able using it? 
In addition, the rest of the channels (skype, slack etc.) work properly for everyone - so it's something specific (I assume) about skype for business.

Thank you!